# Error in creating a flow map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flow-map

I'm trying to create a flow map using [FlowMapGenerator](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2012/09/12/generating-distributive-flow-maps-with-arcgis/). My map is trying to visually show the movement of professional soccer referees to various venues throughout the season. I plan to have several maps, one for each referee. I have a shapefile of points of each referee's home town that also contains information about each of them. I also have a shapefile of points of each team's location that also contains information about each team.

For the first map, the referee lives in New Jersey. I exported his information from the referee shapefile as an independent shapefile to use as the source point. I then added a new attribute to the team data containing the number of times he visited each venue this season to use as a Z-Value. I then exported the information of only the venues he had visited as a new independent shapefile to use as the destination points so that no venue would have a Z-Value of 0.

When I run the toolbox to create the flowmap, I get the following error:[image: Error]

Does anyone have any idea what I might need to fix to get the flowmap to generate?

Comment: Sounds like an incorrect data type in the set you're running the tool on. A quick search on that error [leads me to believe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) you're feeding it a double/float number when it expects an integer. That or if MAXOF is actually the value it's choking on, that's obviously a string and not a number.

Comment: That would make sense, but the attribute that is supposed to determine the thickness of the flow lines is a short integer. I'm fairly certain that there is no value called MAXOF among the attributes of my shapefiles.

Comment: There are comments on both the tool download page and the blog page you link to that mention this error: "If using this tool you may experience the following error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'MAXOF." If so, set the output "cell size" to "as specified below". A good value to use for the sample data linked in this contribution is 50000." The value is given as 200,000 in the other comment. There's a reply that this fix didn't work for someone, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @ChrisW:

> There are comments on both the tool download page and the blog page
>   you link to that mention this error: "If using this tool you may
>   experience the following error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int()
>   with base 10: 'MAXOF." If so, set the output "cell size" to "as
>   specified below". A good value to use for the sample data linked in
>   this contribution is 50000." The value is given as 200,000 in the
>   other comment. There's a reply that this fix didn't work for someone,
>   but worth a shot.